# zip -j command, what does the -j option mean?

Tags: command-line, zip

Wondering what is the `-j` option mean in the `zip` command. I found the explanation as following:

```
-j
Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current path).
```

But not quite sure what it is exact mean? Can anyone explain it using the following command as an example?

```
C:\programs\zip -j myzipfile file1 file2 file3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will make more sense with a different example:

```
C:\programs\zip myzipfile a/file1 b/file2 c/file3
```

Normally this would result in a zip containing three "subdirs":

```
a/
+ file1

b/
+ file2

c/
+ file3
```

With -j, you get:

```
./
+ file1
+ file2
+ file3
```

Comment: I c. So the -j command just ignore the directory path, only put the file name in the current folder?

Answer (score 1):

in that case it won't do anything special.

but if, for example you type

```
C:\programs\zip -j myzipfile directory1
```

and `directory1` contains subdirectories, all the files you zip, when extracted, will be put in the same directory, regardless what subdirectory they were in originally.

Comment: "When extraction" makes sense. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

With the Linux zip command, if you use the -j option with the -i option, the -j may need to be after the -i.  Below, the -r means recursive from 'directory1':

```
   C:\programs\zip -r myzipfile.zip directory1 -i subDirectoryA/*.txt -j
```

If the -j is earlier in the command, the resulting zip file may be empty.

Answer (score -4):

-j is "**J**unk pathnames"